# Como criar um .bat para executar arquivo em rede

Tags: .net, windows, cmd, redes

bat que está localmente em uma rede de vários computadores, um tem uma gravadora e os outros não, a que não tem a gravadora eu uso um .bat com o seguinte código via rede local, para pegar os arquivos dos cds.

```
net use d: /del /y
net use d: \\lab05\d /y
```

Eu queria saber como faz para executar a gravadora em todas as máquinas de uma vez só, todas elas tem esse .bat mas preciso abrir uma por uma, oque eu estava tentando era faz algo assim .bat

```
net use H: \\pc01\lab05.bat
net use I: \\pc02\lab05.bat
net use J: \\pc03\lab05.bat
```

só que eu não sei se o net use funciona exatamente dessa forma.

Eu consigo criar pastas compartilhadas entre esses computadores, seria tipo fazer um acesso remoto mas só para abrir esse .bat que está na área de trabalho.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode instalar o [PsExec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) e depois executar o comando remotamente.

```
psexec \\pc01 C:\Users\NomeDoUsuario\Desktop\lab05.bat
psexec \\pc02 C:\Users\NomeDoUsuario\Desktop\lab05.bat
psexec \\pc03 C:\Users\NomeDoUsuario\Desktop\lab05.bat
```