# Abrir vários programas em áreas de trabalho diferentes usando script no windows 10

Tags: windows, batch, powershell, windows-10

Estou querendo abrir alguns programas em telas de trabalho diferente que tenho que usar com frequência. E queria saber como faço um script para automatizar isso.

Fiz um pequeno e simples script .bat para facilitar isso

```
echo Abrindo o Netbeans
start /d "C:\Program Files\NetBeans 8.2\bin\" netbeans64.exe

echo Abrindo o XAMPP
start /d "C:\xampp\" xampp-control.exe

echo Abrindo PowerShell
start /d "%SystemRoot%\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\" powershell.exe
```

Também gosto de abrir o Spotify, Onenote, Navegador, mas queria que isso abrisse em outra área de trabalho.

Estou usando o Windows 10 PRO.

Comment: Se estiver na mesma rede veja essa pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/203174

Comment: @LaércioLopes Quero abrir no meu próprio computador. E queria abrir certo programas em certas áreas de trabalho no Windows 10 PRO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tem como fazer isso baixando o [VDesk](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk/releases/) (VDeskSetup-1.0.2.msi) e instalando-o. Quando acabar a instalação perceberá que um novo comando estará disponível no cmd, o 'vdesk'. Com isso, basta utilizar o comando vdesk para executar aplicativos em uma nova área de trabalho ou em uma área de trabalho específica, observe os exemplos:

```
vdesk run:notepad
```

Executa o notepad em uma nova área de trabalho.

```
vdesk on:5 run:notepad
```

Executa o notepad na área de trabalho 5.

Pra ver mais exemplos leia [este artigo](https://github.com/eksime/VDesk/blob/master/README.md).
Como é um comando disponível no cmd, tem como colocar em um *.bat, que é o seu objetivo, apenas substitua notepad pelo seu aplicativo e defina a área de trabalho desejável.